# R: Display list-derived class as vector in tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I have to make frequent use of multidimensional complex numbers of the form 1 + 1i + 1j + 1ij (to give one 2D example) and I am trying to define a simple class to facilitate common calculations.

When dealing with multiple such numbers, I have opted to use a list-of-vectors representation. However, I still want this derived list class to look and feel like a vector.

I had no problem with simple printing:

```
ncmplx <- setClass("ncmplx", contains = "list")

format.ncmplx <- function(x, ...) {
  f <- function(y) {
    paste(format(as.numeric(y), ...), c('', 'i', 'j', 'ij'), 
          sep = '', collapse = '+')
  }
  unlist(lapply(x, f))
}

setMethod("show", "ncmplx", function(object) {
    print(format(object))
})

a <- ncmplx(list(1:4, 2:5))
```

Using `print(a)` displays `[1] "1+2i+3j+4ij" "2+3i+4j+5ij"` which is basically what I'd like.

The question is, how do I get a similar display in a `tibble`? I have followed this guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/extending.html but it uses an underlying vector for everything, rather than a list, which seems to make things easier. Here is what I tried:

```
library(tibble)

pillar_shaft.ncmplx <- function(x, ...) {
  out <- format(x)
  out[is.na(x)] <- NA
  pillar::new_pillar_shaft_simple(out, align = "right")
}

a <- ncmplx(list(1:4, 2:5))
b <- tibble(x = 1:2, a = a)

print(b)
```

But the result still displays a list-based summary of the form `<int [4]>` rather than the format that I would like `1+2i+3j+4ij`.

I can sort of hack the `obj_sum()` function so that the summary of my list contents is actually a direct representation of the list contents, but this seems roundabout. Is there a way to tell `tibble` to simply format my list using the `format()` function rather than `obj_sum()`?

Comment: Haven't run your code yet, but can you just pass the last result to `unnest`?

Comment: @camille Not exactly because for all calculations, the different components really should stick together. `unnest` simply unpacks everything, thereby defeating the purpose of packing them together in a list to begin with. What I'm looking for in this particular question is primarily visual more than anything else, so that I can tell at a glance what sort of components there are without them being hidden in an unhelpful `int [4]` summary.

Comment: So you're trying to get a data frame/tibble in which one column shows text in the format `"1+2i+3j+4ij"`, rather than integers? Because `<int [4]>` means there's a list of 4 integers but *not* the formatted text. If that's the case, I think it's the `show` function that throws things off, since it prints the lists of integers, not the formatted representation

Comment: @camille I just need to figure out what formatting function tibble is using to display lists. I can certainly add a column of text, but the point of making this class is that I shouldn't have to if I define a standard representation for my derived class. The issue is that I don't understand which formatter tibble is using for lists, because it's not `format` and it's not `pillar_shaft`. As for `show`, isn't it currently printing my `format` function, which is text rather than integers?

Comment: No, with `show(a)` I get `An object of class "ncmplx"
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 5`

Comment: @camille Good call! I forgot that show() is S4 rather than S3 when writing up the minimal example. I edited the code so that show() and print() result in the same output but no dice for the tibble as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a good opportunity to learn about the `vctrs` package. In short, `vctrs` defines a record-style class using `new_rcrd()` function. I recreated my basic 2D complex number from above based on the instructions in this vignette: https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/master/vignettes/s3-vector.Rmd

```
new_cmplx2 <- function(rr = double, ri = double(), ir = double(), ii = double) {
  vec_assert(rr, ptype = double())
  vec_assert(ri, ptype = double())
  vec_assert(ir, ptype = double())
  vec_assert(ii, ptype = double())

  new_rcrd(list(rr = rr, ri = ri, ir = ir, ii = ii), class = "vctrs_cmplx2")
}

cmplx2 <- function(rr = 0, ri = 0, ir = 0, ii = 0) {
  c(rr, ri, ir, ii) %<-% vec_cast_common(rr, ri, ir, ii, .to = double())
  c(rr, ri, ir, ii) %<-% vec_recycle_common(rr, ri, ir, ii)

  new_cmplx2(rr, ri, ir, ii)
}

format.vctrs_cmplx2 <- function(x, ...) {
  rr <- field(x, "rr")
  ri <- field(x, "ri")
  ir <- field(x, "ir")
  ii <- field(x, "ii")

  out <- paste0(rr, "+", ri, "i+", ir, "j+", ii, "ij")
  out[is.na(rr) | is.na(ri) | is.na(ir) | is.na(ii)] <- NA

  out
}

vec_ptype_abbr.vctrs_cmplx2 <- function(x) "cmplx2"
vec_ptype_full.vctrs_cmple2 <- function(x) "complex2d"
```

Since `vctrs` is a tidyverse project, it's not surprising that integration with `tibble` works exactly as intended:

```
tibble(x = 1:2, a = cmplx2(rr=1:2))
```

This results in the expected column entries for `a`: `1+0i+0j+0ij, 2+0i+0j+0ij`.